# What's an efficient method to extract only the rows with the first occurrence from a data set?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with patient encounters, and want to extract only the oldest encounter for each patient (which can be done using the sequential encounter ID). The code I came up with works, but I'm sure there are more efficient ways to perform this task using dplyr. What approach would you recommend?

Example with 10 encounters for 4 patients:

```
encounter_ID <- c(1021, 1022, 1013, 1041, 1007, 1002, 1003, 1043, 1085, 1077)
patient_ID <- c(855,721,821,855,423,423,855,721,423,855)
gender <- c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0)
df <- data.frame(encounter_ID, patient_ID, gender)
```

Result (desired and obtained):

```
    encounter_ID    patient_ID  gender
    1003            855         0
    1022            721         0
    1013            821         1
    1002            423         1
```

**My approach**

1) Extract a list of the unique patients

```
list.patients <- unique(df$patient_ID)
```

2) Create an empty data frame to receive our output of the first encounter per patient

```
one.encounter <- data.frame()
```

3) Go through each patient on the list to extract their first encounter and populate our data frame

```
for (i in 1:length(list.patients)) {
one.patient <- df %>% filter(patient_ID==list.patients[i])
one.patient.ordered <- one.patient[order(one.patient$encounter_ID),]
first.encounter <- head(one.patient.ordered, n=1)
one.encounter <- rbind(one.encounter, first.encounter)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally R works fastest if you vectorize operations. Therefore the question is what you mean when you ask for more efficient ways to solve this?

To illustrate this I show you a solution in `base R` and run a `microbenchmark`:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(myfun1(),myfun2(),myfun3())
Unit: microseconds
     expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq     max neval
 myfun1() 3997.1 4416.10 6086.848 5129.65 6215.6 64014.4   100
 myfun2()  834.7  993.50 1404.901 1083.95 1247.5 20456.2   100
 myfun3()  133.3  162.75  258.533  193.75  233.8  3561.7   100
```

Your solution is `myfun1()`, @SmitM `dplyr`-version is `myfun2()` and my solution (`myfun3`) looks like this:

```
df_ordered=df[order(df$patient_ID,df$encounter_ID),]
df_ordered[match(unique(df_ordered$patient_ID),df_ordered$patient_ID),]
```

Now you can choose what you like most: `dplyr` solutions are very nice to read and I think also can be exported into other programming languages. The `base R` solutions are very fast, but usually not as nice to read and to the best of my knowledge can't be exported into other languages.

I posted the `base R`-version here because it is relatively nice to read, because every function does what it is called like - still `dplyr` looks nicer though.

Comment: Hi 5th, I should have been more specific when I said "more efficient", but like you guessed,  I was thinking of execution time. Thank you for this great illustration of how to compare results using microbenchmark, and for the suggested (faster) option!

Comment: No problem. Yeah the `microbenchmark`-package is very handy :D Btw the `data.table`-package can outperform `base R` functions in terms of execution speed. Usually `dplyr` can't. Btw the website tour gives you +2 reputation (i think), if you want to gain the right to upvote ;)

Comment: Ah, another good tip! I've consulted StackOverflow many times, but only now created an account and was wondering where the upvote option was :-). Looks like I'm only missing 2 points to get there, and will look for the website tour--thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a base R solution, it is possible to do this efficiently without dplyr

`duplicated` will code the first row it encounters with a certain patient id as `FALSE`, and all subsequent rows with that same patient id as `TRUE` (Here, I've reversed that by adding `!` before `duplicated`), so you can use it to select only the first encounter if you've ordered your dataframe by encounter_ID

```
df <- df[order(df$encounter_ID),] #order dataframe by encounter id
#subset to rows that are not duplicates of a previous encounter for that patient
first <- df[!duplicated(df$patient_ID),]
```

Answer (score 4):

Since OP asked for an efficient method in terms of execution time, here is a benchmark of the answers in addition to a `data.table` way.

[image]

```
#Unit: milliseconds
#            expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#          OP(df) 1354.49200 1398.15245 1481.16068 1467.31151 1531.93056 2124.05586   100
#        Mike(df)  587.33074  606.33194  649.87766  621.65719  658.96548 1076.12302   100
#   Fernandes(df)  177.80735  182.97910  206.64074  185.91444  198.83281  430.96393   100
#       `5th`(df)   60.55170   64.98082   77.55248   67.73171   71.54677  208.47656   100
#       SmitM(df)   52.70000   53.93696   59.05506   54.84035   58.92260  175.24284   100
#   Jan_Boyer(df)   30.70666   33.44665   43.04396   34.46983   35.69736  223.02998   100
#  data_table(df)   11.51547   12.38410   14.60907   13.08038   15.25540   43.71229   100
# Moody_dplyr(df)  234.08792  241.02003  260.19283  245.20301  259.82435  517.03117   100
# Moody_baseR(df)   67.05192   72.00578   89.50914   74.64688   77.58169  299.56125   100
```

**code and data**

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

n <- 1e6
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(encounter_ID = sample(1000:1999, size = n, replace = TRUE), 
                 patient_ID = sample(700:900, n, TRUE), 
                 gender = sample(0:1, n, TRUE))

benchmark <- microbenchmark(
  OP(df),
  Mike(df),
  Fernandes(df),
  `5th`(df),
  SmitM(df),
  Jan_Boyer(df),
  data_table(df),
  Moody_dplyr(df),
  Moody_baseR(df)
)

autoplot(benchmark)
```

The solutions so far.

```
Mike <- function(df) {
  df %>%  
    arrange(patient_ID, encounter_ID) %>% 
    group_by(patient_ID) %>% 
    filter(row_number()==1)
}

SmitM <- function(df) {
  df %>% 
    group_by(patient_ID, gender) %>% 
    summarise(encounter_ID = min(encounter_ID))
}

Fernandes <- function(df) {
  x <- dplyr::arrange(df, encounter_ID)
  x[!duplicated(x$patient_ID),]
}

`5th` <- function(df) {
  df_ordered <- df[order(df$patient_ID, df$encounter_ID), ]
  df_ordered[match(unique(df_ordered$patient_ID), df_ordered$patient_ID), ]
}

Jan_Boyer <- function(df) {
  df <- df[order(df$encounter_ID),] 
  df[!duplicated(df$patient_ID),]
}

data_table <- function(df) {
  setDT(df, key = 'encounter_ID')
  df[df[, .I[1], by = patient_ID]$V1]
}

OP <- function(df) {
  list.patients <- unique(df$patient_ID)
  one.encounter <- data.frame()

  for (i in 1:length(list.patients)) {
    one.patient <- df %>% filter(patient_ID == list.patients[i])
    one.patient.ordered <- one.patient[order(one.patient$encounter_ID), ]
    first.encounter <- head(one.patient.ordered, n = 1)
    one.encounter <- rbind(one.encounter, first.encounter)
  } 
}

Moody_dplyr <- function(df) {
  df %>% group_by(patient_ID) %>% top_n(-1,encounter_ID)
}

Moody_baseR <- function(df) {
  subset(df, as.logical(ave(encounter_ID, patient_ID, FUN = function(x) x == min(x))))
}
```

Comment: I knew `data.table`  would be faster :D But why the heck are the times so different in our benchmarks? Are you using linux maybe? Mine was done on a windows machine

Comment: @5th It might be the size of the `df`. Have you tried the benchmark with the same data I generated? I'm on Linux, yes.

Comment: yeah that makes sense. I somehow overlooked that you generated a bigger dataset.

Comment: Thanks for integrating my answer, I added an option, would you mind adding it as well ?

Comment: I just came here and after reading the answers was planning on creating a similar benchmark (using my 100K rows dataset), but Markus beat me to it! Thank you all for your useful suggestions and comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
          group_by(patient_ID, gender) %>% 
          summarise(encounter_ID = min(encounter_ID))
```

Comment: While this solution works if you had 100 variables in your df you would have to put all of them in your `group_by` statement so they would be retained in `df2`. This might slow down your data step considerably

Comment: Thank you, SmitM! it's useful to see this option. Indeed, Mike is right, the actual dataset has many more columns, making this solution difficult to use in practice.

Comment: you can group by patient only, then merge the result to the original dataset with `left_join`. This works also in base R with something like `merge(df, aggregate(encounter_ID ~ patient_ID, df , min))` . Very readable in my opinion, but slower than several solutions mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

something like this  In the `dplyr` code below I would sort by the two ids then group by patient. Using `row_numer()==1` in the filter statement will grab the smallest `encouter_id` per patient because you sorted by both variables and group_by patient_id.  :

```
encounter_ID <- c(1021, 1022, 1013, 1041, 1007, 1002, 1003, 1043, 1085, 1077)
patient_ID <- c(855,721,821,855,423,423,855,721,423,855)
gender <- c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0)
df <- data.frame(encounter_ID, patient_ID, gender)

library(dplyr)



df2 <- df %>%  
        arrange(patient_ID, encounter_ID) %>% 
        group_by(patient_ID) %>% 
        filter(row_number()==1)
```

Comment: @AdamSampson, interesting ... does `filter(row_number...` work with db objects? I haven't tried it, but I typically deal in-memory most of the time.

Comment: @AdamSampson, please put your comment back in, it had more context than my (now-deleted) comment did!

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
x = dplyr::arrange(df, encounter_ID)
x[!duplicated(x$patient_ID),]
#  encounter_ID patient_ID gender
#1         1002        423      1
#2         1003        855      0
#4         1013        821      1
#6         1022        721      0
```

Comment: Thank you, Fernandes, and @jan-boyer! I had looked into duplicated() but wasn't sure how to make sure I got the first encounter. It's obvious now that you two shared your suggestions -- much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `top_n` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(patient_ID) %>% top_n(-1,encounter_ID)
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# # Groups:   patient_ID [4]
#   encounter_ID patient_ID gender
#          <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1         1022        721      0
# 2         1013        821      1
# 3         1002        423      1
# 4         1003        855      0
```

It's not super fast but it's the idomatic `dplyr` way.

With base `R` this is much faster:

```
subset(df, as.logical(ave(encounter_ID, patient_ID, FUN = function(x) x == min(x))))
```